# Anchor tag isn't calling the onClick function in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to update my component state when you click on an anchor tag inside the render method. I've tried binding inside the constructor, but still the console.log isn't being called. Below is my code. Please help. This is holding me back from progressing lol.

This is modified code based on my previous question here on stackoverflow.

```
const React = require('react');


class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(...props) {
    super(...props);
    this.setActiveTab = this.setActiveTab.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      currentPage: "/"
    }
  }

  setActiveTab(e) {
    console.log(e.target)
    this.setState({
      currentPage: e.target.href 
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { path } = this.props
    let classString = path === this.state.currentPage ? 'nav-item is-tab is-active' : 'nav-item is-tab'

    return (
      <nav className="nav">

        <div className="nav-left">
          <a className="nav-item">
            <h1>CREATORS NEVER DIE</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className="nav-right nav-menu">
          <a href="/" className={classString} onClick={this.setActiveTab}>
            Home
          </a>
        </div>


      </nav>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Navbar;
```

Comment: you used `href='/'` that's why, remove `href` from `a` or use `href='javascript:void(0)'`

Comment: Your anchor tag has a `href`. The `onClick` won't fire because the link is taking you to another page.

Comment: @MayankShukla I removed the href and still nothing showing in console

Comment: @dileet.. did u got answer to ur question? what did u do to make it work?

Answer (score 28):

You need `e.preventDefault()` in the click handler.

It's firing but the default behavior of an anchor is to refresh the page, so it's just rerendering immediately.

Comment: Where exactly are we supposed to call this? My `onClick` handler doesn't have any reference to `e` or anything like that.

Comment: handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('The link was clicked.');
  };

Comment: <a href="#" className={classString} onClick={this.setActiveTab}>

Comment: @44kksharma it will push extra # in URL. Use href='javascript:void(0)' instead of href="#"

Answer (score 9):

Check the working snippet, both the ways are working, either remove the `href` or use `href='javascript:void(0)'` console is printing the proper value on click of Home:

```js
class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.setActiveTab = this.setActiveTab.bind(this)
      this.state = {
         currentPage: '',
      }
  }

  setActiveTab(e) {
      console.log(e.target);
  }

  render() {
      return (
         <div className="nav-right nav-menu">
           
            <a onClick={this.setActiveTab}>
               Home1
            </a>

            <br/>

            <a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick={this.setActiveTab}>
              Home2
            </a>
          
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Navbar/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Hmm could this have something to with me rendering react on the server... Because I see it works, but it's not working on my end.

Comment: sorry, don't have idea about serverside rendering.

Answer (score 4):

Researching the issue it appears you need to prevent the default of the anchor tag. Also if you create an arrow function you are able to handle the this.

Prevent default info can be found on React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Hope this helps.

```
 const React = require("react");

class Navbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(...props) {
        super(...props);
        this.setActiveTab = this.setActiveTab.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            currentPage: "/",
        };
    }

    setActiveTab = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target);
        this.setState({
            currentPage: e.target.href,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { path } = this.props;
        let classString =
            path === this.state.currentPage ? "nav-item is-tab is-active" : "nav-item is-tab";

        return (
            <nav className="nav">
                <div className="nav-left">
                    <a className="nav-item">
                        <h1>CREATORS NEVER DIE</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div className="nav-right nav-menu">
                    <a href="/" className={classString} onClick={this.setActiveTab}>
                        Home
                    </a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Alternatively you can have Button on grid column instead of link to perform activity.

1) Button way : 
<Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={(event) => {
          this.handleCellClick(event, cellValues);
        }}
      >
        ...View Full List
      </Button>

2) Link to work
<a href="#" onClick={this.setActiveTab}>
      ...View Full List
                    </a>
  setActiveTab = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
}
```