# Hyperlink click event not getting invoked

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm building hyperlinks dynamically as per follows. I'm able to see the multiple hyperlink in reactjs ag grid.

But onHyperLinkClick is never getting invoked. I see the error in console as "Uncaught ReferenceError: onHyperLinkClick is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement: onclick....". Any suggestions please?

I tried both onClick=... and click=... events on the "<a.. >" tag, but no luck.

```
    myTestRenderer:

       function myTestFunction = (props.value) =>
        {

const onHyperLinkClick = () =>
            {
                alert('onHyperLinkClick');
            }


            var linkText= "";
            var i; 
            let value = props.value;
            for(i=0;i < value.length;i++)
            {
        
                linkText= "<a href='#' onClick={onHyperLinkClick}>" + value.product[i].productId + "</a>";
                linkText+="<br/>"; 
            }
        
        return (<div style={{cursor:'pointer'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{_html: linkText}} />);
        
            
        };
        
        
        MainFile:
        import MyTestRenderer from myTestRenderer;
        ...
        ....
        {headeName:'Test', field:'test', cellRendererFramework:MyTestRenderer};
    
    <AgGridReact columnDefs={...} rowData={...}>
```

Comment: seems you have a bug, Try deleting the " ' " where you have `onClick='{onHyperLinkClick}`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I just edited my question. There was a typo from my side. I still get the same error even if I dont put the single quotes: onClick={onHyperLinkClick}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292187/anchor-tag-isnt-calling-the-onclick-function-in-react
check this out..