# Next and Back button functionality not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three pages to be displayed by the click of next and back button and by default first page would be shown (ExternalDamage ) and clicking on NEXT the second page would be shown and BACK button would take to the last page, but its not updating the state ?
I need to use state to update the count of the array index but its not updating the index

```
    /* eslint-disable consistent-return */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import classnames from 'classnames';
import ScreenDamage from './ScreenDamage';
import Battery from './Battery';
import ExternalDamage from './ExternalDamage';
import Footer from './Footer';
import styles from './manualCheck.module.scss';
import VerticalSpacing from '../../core/VerticalSpacing/VerticalSpacing';
// import AdditionalChecks from './AdditionalChecks'


const ManualCheck = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const item = [
    <ExternalDamage />,
    <ScreenDamage />,
    <Battery />,
  ];

  const handleBackButton = () => {
    if (index !== 0) {
      setIndex(index - 1);
      console.log(index);
    }
  };

  const handleNextButton = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1);
    console.log(index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {item[index]}
        <div className={styles.footer}>
          <VerticalSpacing size={ABLE_SPACING_SIZE.spacing2x} />
            {/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
            <a
              href="#"
              onClick={() => handleBackButton()}
            >
              Back
            </a>
            {/* eslint-enable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
            {/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
            <a
              href="#"
              onClick={() => handleNextButton()}
            >
              Next
            </a>
            {/* eslint-enable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */}
        </div>
      <VerticalSpacing size={ABLE_SPACING_SIZE.spacing15x} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ManualCheck;
```

Comment: What is the <InlineLink> ? and did you create you wrapper function correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `e.preventDefault()` in the `handleBackButton()` and `handleNextButton()` as such :

```js
const handleBackButton = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (index !== 0) {
    setIndex(index - 1);
    console.log(index);
  }
};

const handleNextButton = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setIndex(index + 1);
  console.log(index);
};
```

The following link might help you in your quest :

[Anchor tag calling the onClick function React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44292584/16067048)

Answer (score 0):

Well your code can be improved as followings:

First, you are not passing any argument to the functions so you should use `onClick` as followings:

```
<a
  href="#"
  onClick={handleBackButton}>
   Back
</a>
<a href="#"
   onClick={handleNextButton}
>
  Next
</a>
```

Also your state is dependent on the previous state. so in order to ensure that you are getting the latest snapshots you must update your state as below:

```
const handleBackButton = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 if (index !== 0) {
  setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex - 1);
  console.log(index);
 }
};

const handleNextButton = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
  console.log(index);
};
```